# How to stretch image to full height of page in bootstrap col?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, row, col

I'm trying to create a login page like this:

[image]

What I created so far looks like this:

[image]

With this code:

```
<div class="control-section" style="max-width: 100% !important;">
        <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100% !important; padding-top: 25px !important;">
                <section>
                    <form id="account" method="post">
                        <h4>LOGIN </h4>
                        <hr />
                        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                                    <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <p>
                                <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a id="resend-confirmation" asp-page="./ResendEmailConfirmation">Resend email confirmation</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8" style="max-width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important;">
                <img src="~/Resources/placeholderimage.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
     <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}

<style>
.container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

.col-md-4 {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}

.col-md-8 {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}

img {
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

</style>
```

As u can see theres an empty white space at the bottom of the page even though I resized my image to huge dimensions, somehow it does not fit to the 100% of my page. How can I set the static height of 100% to my image? Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: post a minimal reproducible example... however, try with `height: 100vh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 100vh instead of 100% on your `img` or `col-md-8`.

1. Possibly the image does not stretch the full width of `col-md-8` in which case you can:

```
img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover; /* cover makes the image stretch the width and height of the container */
}
```

And you can also make sure the `col-md-8` takes up 100% of the height like this.

```
col-md-8 {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Add CSS Media Query to change image fit on screens below 993px

```
@media and screen(max-width: 992px {
   img{
     object-fit: contain;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work aswell. Image is still not showing full width. Maybe its because of the image dimensions? Cant I auto stretch it or something?

Comment: I want the height to be 100% and width can change (in case for mobile dimension)

Comment: Yes, it could be the image dimensions, in which case `height:100vh , width:100%` and `object-fit:cover;` should do. It would be best if you could show us a fiddle so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, created fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NielsSchutte/7egdur12/#&togetherjs=tVAjjDRHQx As u can see the width is 100% but height is still fixed to height of image and not full height of page

Comment: If i make the following changes: .col-md-4 {
        height: 100vh !important;
    } It kind of works but that col has a height of 100% to, it does not look good on mobile.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure what you want the image to look like on mobile. The way I see it is you can have the image shrinking with the browser or staying large. You can add a CSS media querie for mobile. `img {object-fit: contain;` I'll edit my answer to show this.

Comment: Check out this fiddle. This is how this kind of page is mostly displayed. https://jsfiddle.net/wanodabraino/ab73ru6x/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Remove height from row and columns and give this class in row m-0

```
<div class="col-md-8"  !important;">
     <class ="bk-one-more-div"style="width: 100%!important; height: 500px>
           <img src="~/Resources/placeholderimage.png"  class="img-fluid  w- 
           100">
     <div/>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi, if i use your code the image is not even showing and theres a vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would advise against it, if you must change the height of the element without changing the size of the parent, you should probably set the `height: 100vh`

> Obviously since the viewport height is not calculated properly or as expected on mobile you should probably try to calculate the height of the `window.innerHeight` on `window.addEventListener('load')` and on `window.addEventListener('resize')` using something like this:

```
const vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`)

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  const vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`)
})
```

> Then applying it to your element as so: `height: calc(var(--vh, 100vh) * 100)`

Obviously a simpler solution would be using `height: 100%` and you would avoid any possible overflow.

Comment: I'm looking for pure css/html answer

Comment: The javascript part isn't necessary, it is just for extended mobile browser support. You can just ignore it if you want to.